# display image in imageButton ....

Tags: imageview, drawable, imagebutton

i have a problem with displaying an image on imageButton...

```
imgWeatherIcon = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mndpImage);

Intent i = getIntent();
            this.iconfile = i.getStringExtra("icon");

            String uri = "drawable/"+ "d" + iconfile;
            System.out.println("* "+ uri);
            int imageBtnResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());
            Drawable dimgbutton = getResources().getDrawable(imageBtnResource);

            imgWeatherIcon.setImageDrawable(dimgbutton);
```

some  System.out.println outputs:

```
        uri = drawable/dsnowing
        imageBtnResource  = 2130837512
        dimgbutton = android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@414733c8
```

the image exist in the drawable folder 
name of the imageButton element (mndpImage) in layout is correct

any idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: I'm confused why you're using the path to the drawable folder and not R.drawable.imageName

Comment: I'm new at android programing... i found this piece of code and now i'm trying to test it... so if you know the right way to do this ... please :)

Comment: If you have items in the drawable folder, instead of using the path to the image you can just use R.drawable.imageName so for an image called dsnowing it would be R.drawable.dsnowing If you have multiple sizes/densities of the images in ldpi/mdpi etc.. it will auto select the correct one based on the device hardware too.

Comment: imgWeatherIcon.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.dsnowing);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
imgWeatherIcon = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mndpImage);
imgWeatherIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dsnowing);
```

Comment: The method setImageDrawable(Drawable) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: Apologies, try setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imageName);

Comment: better... but still not good... the image apears behind the "sample image" that is used for the imageviews without resource ... if you understand what i mean  ... here is the result http://shrani.si/f/M/gV/3ny24MGb/problem.png

Comment: That image must be assigned somewhere, either in code or xml. Find the reference to the image name and remove it.

Comment: GREAT JOB! it was inside the XML file .... now i have to figure out how to insert the variable instead of the "dsnowing"... couse i call the images from XML file...

Comment: String test= iconfile;
imgWeatherIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.test);

doesn't work ... any idea ?

Comment: Unless there is a specific reason you need to get the ID of the drawable from a string in the XML file I would avoid it and just use R.drawable.imageName instead.

Comment: this activity is an extension of the listview ... when i click on a element of the listview the data of that element are send in this activity ... so get the title and the description + the image ... this is why i need  to call it trough the variable .... the  iconfile is "dsnowing" so i just need to save it as a variable and run it in this setBackgroundResource ....

Comment: int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(iconfile, "drawable", getPackageName()); imgWeatherIcon.setBackgroundResource(resID);